# In scipy.sparse, when to use csc_matrix and csr_matrix, and what is the difference to _array and _matrix

Tags: python, performance, scipy, sparse-matrix

If I have some type of diagonal matrix, but there are more rows than columns, is `csc_matrix` more efficient because I am compressing each row per column. Conversely, if there are more columns, should I be using `csr_matrix`?

Also, what is the main difference between `csc_matrix` and `csc_array`?

Comment: You can look at the attributes, `indptr`, `indices`, `data`.  In your case `csc` will have a smaller `indptr` (#columns+1).  `_array` is new development, and for now a shallow layer upon the older `_matrix`.  Read the docs.

Comment: The original sparse math was developed for large linear algebra problems, with 2d matrices, matrix multiplication, and solving.   Hence scipy sparse objects look like `np.matrix`.  But that is being phased out, so there's a slow movement toward making them more general like `np.ndarray`,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's relatively easy, and cheap timewise, to convert between formats.  `scipy.sparse` does some of that automatically for you.  For example most calculations are done in CSR or CSC format.  The transpose of a CSR is a CSC.  Row/column sums, and a lot of indexing is done with matrix multiplication in the CSR/CSC formats.  Often it is easiet to define the matrix/array with COO style input, which are then converted to CSR/CSC for computations (and conversion to dense/array).